# iOS Getting UIImage filename by parsing nib

Tags: ios

I'm trying to make a tool that lets me design my GUIs in Interface Builder and then export those GUIs into a XML or plist file for dynamically loading at runtime.  I can get all of the various properties I need from UIButtons, UIImages, etc, except for the filenames of the images shown on various elements.

I was wondering if there was any way to get some little-known property from the various UI objects (like the various keys or IDs I see in the nib) and use that to help perform a search through the nib XML to find what I need.  For example a given button has "ID" "34567875492", and I could then search the nib XML for that ID and a nearby filename for an image.

Or, I could use a better way to develop runtime GUIs without WebViews or writing totally-custom XML with no WSIWYG editor...  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the structure of a `.xib` is like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<archive type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.iPad.XIB" version="8.00">
    <data>
        <array class="NSMutableArray" key="IBDocument.RootObjects" id="1000">
            <object class="IBUIView" id="766721923">
                <array class="NSMutableArray" key="NSSubviews">
                    <object class="IBUIImageView" id="1009194791">
```

You could parse the XML with your favorite parser and pull out the values corresponding to any `UIImageView`s and so on to get objects having appropriate `class` attributes (likely `UIImageView` and `UIButton`) and then inspect the nodes underneath them for promising keys. I'd expect with future versions of IB this will change however.